# How to simulate this truncated normal?

Tags: simulation, truncated-normal-distribution

I am trying to simulate data with two values:

Start is a truncated normal with mean mu, sd sigma and min 0. Finish is also truncated normal. But X% are half or less of start. How can I simulate finish?

I will be using SAS (but this is NOT SAS specific).  Start is

```
 start = max(&BLSR + rannor(123)*&BLSR, 0); /*Rate at start */
```

and I want to simulate a finish where X% of the values will be less than half of start.

Comment: I'm not too savvy at reading SAS code (so maybe the answer to this question is embedded in there) but what are the truncation limits for Finish?

Comment: The minimum for both is 0.  There's no maximum